# regular expression in java search

Tags: java, regex

How can I with `regex` find string "executeQuery" but not if whole string has "vo" or "Viewobject".

Examples:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); --> CORRECT
super.executeQueryForCollection(object, object1, i); --> CORRECT
voOEPoDEStruktura.executeQuery(); --> WRONG
ViewObject.executeQuery(); --> WRONG
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this must be accomplished by a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(?!.*(?:vo|ViewObject)).*executeQuery.*` is the regex which will match the specifications. I didn't use capturing groups because you didnt specify that you want to capture anything.

You should use the solution with contains because it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need a regex. You can use `contains` instead. Your condition would be:

```
str.contains("executeQuery") && !(str.contains("vo") || str.contains("Viewobject"))
```

Comment: +1. Remember: if at first you have a problem and then you decide to solve it using regular expressions, you will suddenly have two problems. Don't over-engineer.

Comment: a bit modification to make it faster

!str.contains("vo") && !str.contains("Viewobject") && str.contains("executeQuery")

Comment: I don't know if that's faster. Provided that majority of lines contain none of these strings, let's examine what happens when parsing the random 50 char line:
`!str.contains("vo") && !str.contains("Viewobject") && 0str.contains("executeQuery")`
Scan 50 chars to find the string contains no vo, scan 50 chars to find the string contains no ViewObject, scan 50 chars to see if string contains executeQuery
`str.contains("executeQuery") && !(str.contains("vo") || str.contains("Viewobject"))
`
Scan the line for executeQuery... and fail 99% of the time, and finish right there.